# how to save on existing video

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, c#

I have this command : `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -r 30 -t 10 E:\test01.flv`

and i am happy with it, but i wonder if i can make it save every 30 minutes so if the power went off i only loses the last 30 minutes.

i use C# to launch and hide `ffmpeg cmd`, so i wonder how to make it save to the same `test01.flv` every 30 minutes?

Comment: Please do not ask [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763031/record-desktop-save-every-30-minutes) on multiple [se] sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flv is a streaming container (unlike mp4). If the file is cut off, it is still valid and playable up to the last complete frame stored on disk. Just calling sync() once in a while is good enough for your use case.